# Gradle build failed, appcompat-v7 issue

Tags: android

I am using easy-ocr-library and wifi-direct-demo library, i have just modified wifi-direct-demo as per my requirement.

I am trying to add easy-ocr-library into wifi-direct-demo library app, 
so i added easy-ocr-library as new module in wifi-direct-demo library.

After adding "easy-ocr-library" as module dependency in "wifi-direct-demo" , i got

Error:Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version 15 declared in library [wifi-direct-demo-m4:easy_ocr_library:unspecified] /Users/nikhildange/Desktop/wifi-direct-demo-m2/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/wifi-direct-demo-m4/easy_ocr_library/unspecified/AndroidManifest.xml
>       Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.wordpress.priyankvex.easyocrscanner" to force usage

So as suggested in Error i added in AndroidManifest.xml file of wifi-direct-demo-m2

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" tools:overrideLibrary="com.wordpress.priyankvex.easyocrscanner"/>
```

After clicking 'Make Project', i am getting below error

```
/Users/nikhildange/Desktop/wifi-direct-demo-m4/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/22.2.1/res/values-v17/values-v17.xml 

Error:(6, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAlignment'.

Error:(10, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.

Error:(10, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.

Error:(13, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.

Error:(17, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginEnd'.

.

.

.

/Users/nikhildange/Desktop/wifi-direct-demo-m4/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/22.2.1/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml

Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.

Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.

Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.

.


.

.

Error:Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/nikhildange/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I am adding gradle file of all 3 modules,

**easy_ocr_library/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile project(':tess-two')
}
```

**tess-two/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
    }
}
```

**wifi-direct-demo-m4/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':easy_ocr_library')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 16
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

After changing an minsdkverson to 15 in AndroidManifest.xml file of wifi-direct-demo-m2

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15"/>
```

i am getting the same error with below screen shot

[image: Screenshot project after synch]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says: uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version 15

So:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" tools:overrideLibrary="com.wordpress.priyankvex.easyocrscanner"/>
```

must be at least

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
```

Try to use sdk 15. And remove tools:overrideLibrary.

Comment: thank Geert for replying!! :) .. but i m still receiving same error.. as i posted above..

Comment: @GreetBerkers i have added screen shot of my project after changing minsdkversion to 15.

Comment: try Clean&Rebuild

Comment: Not sure, but try to use compileSdkVersion 22 in all three projects. Can you try this and share the result? And also update Android SDK to latest versions

Comment: Thanks, guy for your help!! i changed my "Compile Sdk Version" to API 22: Android 5.1, which earlier was API 16.  "Build Tools Version" to 22.0.1 in project structure. Currently , project is BUILD SUCCESSFULL.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you specified two versions of the SDK tool in your gradle files, It will avoid some error to using one version of the SDK tool in all these gradle files, like below :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

  ...
}
```